# python sqlite named parameter containing dash

Tags: python, sqlite, named-parameters

I'm trying to insert a record into an sqlite database using named parameters in python (with the sqlite3 module). 
The values I want to insert are in a dictionary, but the dictionary keys might contain dashes, for example  `{'request-id': 100, 'year': '2015'}`.
I'm trying to execute the following:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS requests (request_id text, year text)''')
query = '''INSERT INTO requests (request_id, year) VALUES (:request-id, :year)'''
cursor.execute(query, {'request-id': 100, 'year': '2015'})
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I get this error during the insert statement:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: id
```

It seems like dashes are not well accepted as named parameters.

There are many workarounds for this, like creating a new dictionary where dashes in the keys are replaced by underscores, but I'd like to know if I could use some escaping technique or something else to avoid that.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your `column names` don't match too. It is `date` in `create` and `year` in `insert`.

Comment: No I guess , the `id` here is referring to inconsistent use of `date` while creating table and `year` thereafter.

Comment: Sorry, it was a cut and paste error, the actual table contains the "year" column. I've edited the question accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `sqlite3_bind_*`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) states that parameter names must be composed of alphanumeric characters, and doesn't mention a way of escaping them.

Your query is probably being parsed as `:request - id`, i.e. `:request` minus `id`, and since there's no such column `id`, SQLite throws an error.

(Also, as Prerak Sola points out, you create the table with a `date` column but try to insert to a `year` column which doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 0):

SQL parameter names have no quoting or escaping mechanism; you have to use the same rules as for an unquoted identifier.